# Plank - multiple workspaces behaviour

Tags: plank

Has there been any progress on making Plank show the "opened application" dots only for the current workspace? There's a request filed as well https://bugs.launchpad.net/plank/+bug/1248689

This is really what is keeping me tied to the awfully performing Gnome with Dash to Dock